# How does MySQL do I/O?

Tags: mysql, c, database

I was wondering how MySQL (and other databases for that matter) work under the hood. Do they use standard C I/O calls like `fseek` to find a record?

Comment: MySQL is open source, you can read it.

Comment: @Barmar Some light bedtime reading?

Comment: There's no single answer to this question, because MySQL has multiple storage engines. Each storage engine implements I/O in different ways, to optimize for different types of work. Even in the default storage engine InnoDB, the answer is complex because it involves multiple layers of buffering changes both in RAM and on disk. Refer to books such as [High Performance MySQL](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781492080503/) or [Understanding MySQL Internals](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-mysql-internals/0596009577/)

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for that. Chapter 10 of Understanding MySQL Internals was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/mysql-8.0/blob/8.0/sql/sql_insert.cc). From a quick review of the file I can confirm that there are multiple check that is been done before and after an insert. It's actually a great idea to review the whole file very interesting.